# NodeJS, Socket IO session and Express session

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session to sync my sessions between socket.io and express.
However, when I set a session via socket.io (with `socket.handshake.session.foo` for example), I can't access on it with express: I got `undefined` with `req.session.foo`.
How can I solve that? What's the problem?
Here's: my code of `app.js`:

```html
// Requires

global.config = require("./config.js");
var express   = require("express");
var session   = require("express-session");
global.sha1   = require("sha1");
global.moment = require("moment");
var rhandler  = require("./handler.js");
global.mySQL  = require("./mysql.js");
var entities  = new require("html-entities").XmlEntities;
global.Users  = {};

var app        = express();
var server     = require("http").createServer(app).listen(config.server.port);
global.Handler = new rhandler();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use("/assets", express.static("public"));

var socketIO = require("socket.io");
var io       = socketIO.listen(server);

var session = require("express-session")({
    secret: config.express.secret,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
});
var sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");

// Use express-session middleware for express
app.use(session);

// Use shared session middleware for socket.io
// setting autoSave:true
io.use(sharedsession(session, {
    autoSave:true
}));

io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.on("login", function(obj, callback) {
        socket.handshake.session.test = "test";
    });
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.session.test);
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Per the doc, you should be accessing `socket.handshake.session.foo`, not `socket.handshake.foo`.

Comment: Yea true, I have failled in my topic. But same problem with this

Comment: When I've tried this in the past, a `session.save()` was required in order to retain modifications.

Comment: Okay, I have put `socket.handshake.session.save();` after `socket.handshake.session.test = "test";`, and work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comments into an answer since it solved your problem.

Per the doc, you should be accessing `socket.handshake.session.foo`, not `socket.handshake.foo`.

And, to retain a modification to the session, I've found you need to add `socket.handshake.session.save()` after modifying the session.